# Запятые в уточняющих оборотах

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые?

В период с 7 по 9 июля (,) по приглашению польских арматурщиков (,) состоялась рабочая поездка…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые не нужны, никаких причин для постановки. Это не уточняющий оборот.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, здесь нет уточнения.